fill form with information (pdf) in java
I'm currently working on a project where I need to programmatically fill out a PDF form. However, I've encountered a hurdle with loading the PDF document using Apache PDFBox's PDDocument.load() method. The code snippet I'm using is as follows:
PDDocument originalDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(originalFormFilePath));

Unfortunately, it seems that the load method is not being recognized, and consequently, I'm unable to load the PDF document successfully. Despite trying various arguments, I haven't been able to resolve this issue.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this problem and how I can go about fixing it. Additionally, if there are alternative libraries or approaches that I could consider for filling out PDF forms programmatically, I'm open to exploring those options as well.
Thank you in advance for your assistance and guidance .

Is it a maven of gradle project? If so have you included the Apache PDFBox depedency in it? It would help to also include your depedencies file in the post, as well as an image of the error shown

@Vled Never include errors, code, etc. as an image. It must be included as a well formatted text. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

The method you mention is for the 2.0.* versions only.

Looking at the javadocs for PDFBox, in the latest version (3.0.2) the PDDocument class doesn't have any static load methods.  But they are present in version 2.0.31 ... the last before the 3.x series.
So, either check your dependency specifications to make sure that you using a 2.x version of PDFBox, or look for examples that work with 3.x.
According to the PDFBox 3.0 Migration guide you should be using the Loader class to load PDF files.  Like this:
try (RandomAccessReadBufferedFile bf =
           new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile("yourfile.pdf");
     PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(bf)) {
    // use document
}

